# Какой язык лучше изучать?

Tags: visual-basic, c++

Какой язык лучше изучать? C++, Basic и т.п.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сначала нужно понять чего вы хотите добиться, а потом выбирать язык.

На Visual Basic обычно делают коммерческие клиентские Windows приложения для доступа к БД через сеть с огромным количеством GUI. Плюс в том что его можно достаточно быстро освоить, экономии времени за счет визуального редактирования GUI, хорошей документации и существовании VBA/VBscript.

На C/C++ можно сделать вообще все что угодно начиная от домашних заданий в школе и заканчивая компиляторами, интерпретаторами других языков/операционными системами, но его очень тяжело освоить, единственный верный метод вменяемо научиться писать на нем это долгие годы практики и чтение специальной литературы.

Я работал с VB6/[VB.Net/Delphi/Java/C#/JavaScript/PHP/C++/C/](http://VB.Net/Delphi/Java/C#/JavaScript/PHP/C++/C/) немного с Perl/Python/Lisp/Haskell/asm. В последний год перешел на С++. До хорошего стиля мне еще очень далеко, в 95% случаев мой код является набором структур с функциями, которые по старинке перемалывают им биты. Сейчас понимаю что нужно было сразу начинать с С++.

В общем изучайте С++ и парадигмы с ним связанные точно не прогадаете. Потом любой другой язык высокого уровня будет казаться просто детской игрушкой.

Comment: @igumnov а на basic можно сделать программу, которая будет распознавать речь с микрофона в текст?

Comment: да, можно. Но много придется писать ручками, так как большинство библиотек, которые были бы удобны в данной задаче, написаны на С/С++.

Comment: @Zow Можно, в вашем случае похоже придется использовать какую-то готовую инструкцию вроде этой.
http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/courses/spsci/compmeth/speech/recognition.html

Если хотите написать нечто подобное с нуля советую глубоко заняться Рядами Фурье/цифровыми фильтрами/статистикой и другими разделами математики связанными с темой.

Comment: лучше поучите Си. И мозги прочистит, и научит многому. Если освоите - быть программистом.

Comment: Годный пример прочистки мозгов в С стиле:

    main(k){float i,j,r,x,y=-16;while(puts(""),y++<15)for(x
    =0;x++<84;putchar(" .:-;!/>)|&IH%*#"[k&15]))for(i=k=r=0;
    j=r*r-i*i-2+x/25,i=2*r*i+y/10,j*j+i*i<11&&k++<111;r=j);}